# It occurs randomly WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium-ios

WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found
Unable to proceed the tests it occurs randomly what to use in catch block to proceed my test

Comment: Remove derived data.

Comment: derived data means from where i need to remove i didnt get it

Comment: Xcode-->Preference-->Locations---> go to Derived data location and delete all data.

Comment: Example:I have pass this derived data path in capabilites if i delete those data it is generating new one how to handle it on daily basis kindly suggest me on this     Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dshrdyurgzrvivahshne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ test.app

Comment: Don't worry just delete all data from DerivedData folder. Its only cached data, for every launch simulator os creates one folder of that application.Though I have not tested but I hope If you delete all files of your application will solve this issue.